# Adding values for missing data combinations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas data frame containing something like the following:

```
person_id   status    year    count
0           'pass'    1980    4
0           'fail'    1982    1
1           'pass'    1981    2
```

If I know that all possible values for each field are:

```
all_person_ids = [0, 1, 2]
all_statuses = ['pass', 'fail']
all_years = [1980, 1981, 1982]
```

I'd like to populate the original data frame with `count=0` for missing data combinations (of person_id, status, and year), i.e. I'd like the new data frame to contain:

```
person_id   status    year    count
0           'pass'    1980    4
0           'pass'    1981    0
0           'pass'    1982    0
0           'fail'    1980    0
0           'fail'    1981    0
0           'fail'    1982    2
1           'pass'    1980    0
1           'pass'    1981    2
1           'pass'    1982    0
1           'fail'    1980    0
1           'fail'    1981    0
1           'fail'    1982    0
2           'pass'    1980    0
2           'pass'    1981    0
2           'pass'    1982    0
2           'fail'    1980    0
2           'fail'    1981    0
2           'fail'    1982    0
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

create a MultiIndex by MultiIndex.from_product() and then `set_index()`, `reindex()`, `reset_index()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

all_person_ids = [0, 1, 2]
all_statuses = ['pass', 'fail']
all_years = [1980, 1981, 1982]
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO("""person_id   status    year    count
0           pass    1980    4
0           fail    1982    1
1           pass    1981    2"""), delim_whitespace=True)
names = ["person_id", "status", "year"]

mind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [all_person_ids, all_statuses, all_years], names=names)
df.set_index(names).reindex(mind, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Comment: Works well - would you be able to explain roughly what each step above is doing? (I've not had to use `reindex` or `reset_index` before, but I'll read up on them shortly).

Comment: `reindex()` aligns the rows to the new index, use `fill_value=0` to fill NaN with 0. I think you can keep the `MultiIndex`, because you can use it to select elements quickly. By `reset_index()` you can convert the index to columns.

Comment: it's mainly like a static way, is there any way we can do it dynamically by date?

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to generate all combinations, then construct a df from this, [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) it with your original df along with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) to fill missing count values with `0`:

```
In [77]:
import itertools
all_person_ids = [0, 1, 2]
all_statuses = ['pass', 'fail']
all_years = [1980, 1981, 1982]
combined = [all_person_ids, all_statuses, all_years]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['person_id', 'status', 'year'], data=list(itertools.product(*combined)))
df1

Out[77]:
    person_id status  year
0           0   pass  1980
1           0   pass  1981
2           0   pass  1982
3           0   fail  1980
4           0   fail  1981
5           0   fail  1982
6           1   pass  1980
7           1   pass  1981
8           1   pass  1982
9           1   fail  1980
10          1   fail  1981
11          1   fail  1982
12          2   pass  1980
13          2   pass  1981
14          2   pass  1982
15          2   fail  1980
16          2   fail  1981
17          2   fail  1982

In [82]:    
df1 = df1.merge(df, how='left').fillna(0)
df1

Out[82]:
    person_id status  year  count
0           0   pass  1980      4
1           0   pass  1981      0
2           0   pass  1982      0
3           0   fail  1980      0
4           0   fail  1981      0
5           0   fail  1982      1
6           1   pass  1980      0
7           1   pass  1981      2
8           1   pass  1982      0
9           1   fail  1980      0
10          1   fail  1981      0
11          1   fail  1982      0
12          2   pass  1980      0
13          2   pass  1981      0
14          2   pass  1982      0
15          2   fail  1980      0
16          2   fail  1981      0
17          2   fail  1982      0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pyjanitor](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor)'s [`complete`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) method.

It accepts column names as input as well as {name: values} dictionaries with the exhaustive list of wanted values to complete:

```
import janitor
df.complete({'person_id': [0,1,2]}, 'status', 'year').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
    person_id  status  year  count
0           0  'fail'  1980      0
1           0  'fail'  1981      0
2           0  'fail'  1982      1
3           0  'pass'  1980      4
4           0  'pass'  1981      0
5           0  'pass'  1982      0
6           1  'fail'  1980      0
7           1  'fail'  1981      0
8           1  'fail'  1982      0
9           1  'pass'  1980      0
10          1  'pass'  1981      2
11          1  'pass'  1982      0
12          2  'fail'  1980      0
13          2  'fail'  1981      0
14          2  'fail'  1982      0
15          2  'pass'  1980      0
16          2  'pass'  1981      0
17          2  'pass'  1982      0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
all_person_ids = [0, 1, 2]
all_statuses = ['pass', 'fail']
all_years = [1980, 1981, 1982]


pd.Series(all_person_ids).to_frame('person_id').merge(pd.Series(all_statuses).to_frame('status'), how='cross')\
    .merge(pd.Series(all_years).to_frame('year'), how='cross')\
    .merge(df1,on=['person_id','status','year'], how='left')\
    .fillna(0)

    person_id status  year  count
0           0   pass  1980    4.0
1           0   pass  1981    0.0
2           0   pass  1982    0.0
3           0   fail  1980    0.0
4           0   fail  1981    0.0
5           0   fail  1982    1.0
6           1   pass  1980    0.0
7           1   pass  1981    2.0
8           1   pass  1982    0.0
9           1   fail  1980    0.0
10          1   fail  1981    0.0
11          1   fail  1982    0.0
12          2   pass  1980    0.0
13          2   pass  1981    0.0
14          2   pass  1982    0.0
15          2   fail  1980    0.0
16          2   fail  1981    0.0
17          2   fail  1982    0.0
```