# Add rows to dataframe which don't exist based on a condition- Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe with features Color, Finish, Shelfs and Wifi.

```
|ID|feature|feature_val|source|
|--|-------|-----------|------|
|1 |Color  | White     | A    |
|1 |Finish | Steel     | A    |
|1 |Shelfs | 2         | B    |
|1 |WiFi   | Y         | B    |
|2 |Shelfs | 3         | A    |
|2 |WiFi   | N         | A    |
|3 |Color  | Black     | B    |
```

My objective is to add rows to ID's which don't have all these features. ID 1 has all the features. ID 2 doesn't have the features "Color" and "Finish" so I want to add these rows to ID 2 where my feature_val will be NaN and source will be "UNK" for Unknown. My final dataframe should look like this:

```
|ID|feature|feature_val|source|
|--|-------|-----------|------|
|1 |Color  | White     | A    |
|1 |Finish | Steel     | A    |
|1 |Shelfs | 2         | B    |
|1 |WiFi   | Y         | B    |
|2 |Color  | NaN       | UNK  |
|2 |Finish | NaN       | UNK  |
|2 |Shelfs | 3         | A    |
|2 |WiFi   | N         | A    |
|3 |Color  | Black     | B    |
|3 |Finish | NaN       | UNK  |
|3 |Shelfs | NaN       | UNK  |
|3 |WiFi   | NaN       | UNK  |
```

I used to the function "complete" from pyjanitor library to achieve this however, pyjanitor is causing installation issues thus, I would like an alternative way to achieve the same without using this library.

```
complete_df = df.complete("ID", "feature", fill_value={"source": "UNK"})
```

There is no fixed feature_val for what color, finish, shelfs, or source will be thus, I cannot use possible solutions mentioned in this link: [Adding values for missing data combinations in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786881/adding-values-for-missing-data-combinations-in-pandas)

Comment: "*I cannot use possible solutions mentioned in this link: Adding values for missing data combinations in Pandas*" -> you have to explain clearly why, else the question is too vague.

Comment: In the link mentioned as a possible solution, the scenario has fixed values for each of the 3 features in the dataframe. In my scenario, only one feature has fixed values, "feature"  thus, I cannot use the solutions mentioned in the link as the solution approach is different